# Adding a background picture to a navigation box

Tags: css, navigation

I have the following CSS for my navigation bar:

```
nav { 
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-width: 1px 0;
  background-color: #000000; 
}

nav li { display: inline; }

nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

However, instead of the black background color, I would like to have a picture. Note that the nav bar is fixed, so the picture behind the nav menu should also be fixed.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about trying the following?

```
nav {
    background-image: url('/url/to/image.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nav { background: #000 url('imageURL.jpg') no-repeat fixed; }
```